# Doing stuff for each record in a recordset

Tags: database, vbscript

I'm working on some code that checks a database for a specific value and returns a string under certain conditions.

I cannot get this code to iterate to the next row in my database results. It appears that my code only checks the first record of the recordset and then continues.

Sometimes my recordset may only have one row, but sometimes it may have many rows. If any of the rows of this recordset have a certain value I want to throw a MsgBox. Not just the first or last record.

Here's my code:

```
'Database Connection Strings.
strServerName = "string"
strDatabase = "string"
strUserName = "string"
strPassword = "string"

'Connection string for SQL Server.
strConn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & strServerName & ";Database=" & strDatabase & ";Uid=" & strUsername & ";Pwd=" & strPassword & ";"

'Create required objects for the session.
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set db = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Create the array of reciever lines and count them.
Set arrayLine = LINES.Value
intNumOfLines = arrayLine.Count
intLineNum = Cint(intNumOfLines)-1
cleanPN2 = array()
skipArray = array("-", " ", "PLATE", "HEAT-TREAT", "PAINT", "MACHINE", "WELD", "MPI")

result = MsgBox ("Scan PO for cert requirements?", vbYesNo, "PO Requirement Scanner")

Select Case result
  Case vbYes
    'Iterate through the reciever lines and look for part numbers.
    For intLineNum = 0 To intNumOfLines
      If intLineNum = intNumOfLines Then
        Exit For
      End If
      Set arrayLine = LINES(intLineNum).Value
      strPN = arrayLine("VENDOR_PART_ID")
      cleanPN = split(strPN, " ")
      For Each iteration in cleanPN
        iteration = LTrim(RTrim(iteration))
        ReDim Preserve cleanPN2(UBound(cleanPN2) + 1)
        cleanPN2(UBound(cleanPN2)) = iteration
      Next
    Next

    'Take any part numbers that were found and search the WO Master for operations that require certs.
    For Each cleanPN3 In cleanPN2
      strSQL = "SELECT USER_3 FROM OPERATION WHERE WORKORDER_BASE_ID = " & "'" & cleanPN3 & "';"
      db.Open strConn, db
      rs.Open strSQL, db
      If Not rs.EOF And Not rs.BOF Then
        strUSER3 = rs("USER_3")
        Do While rs("USER_3") = Null
          strUSER3 = rs("USER_3").MoveNext
        Loop
        If (strUSER3 <> Null) Or (strUSER3 <> "") Then
          MsgBox "Certifications are required for part number " & cleanPN3 & "!", vbOKOnly
        End If
      End If
      rs.Close
      db.Close
    Next

    MsgBox "PO Scan Complete!"

  Case vbNo
    MsgBox("PO Scan Cancelled!")
End Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything else is working as you wish

```
  rs.Open strSQL, db
  If Not rs.BOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If Len(Trim(Cstr(rs.fields("USER_3").value)) > 0 Then
          MsgBox "Certifications are required for part number " & cleanPN3 & "!", vbOKOnly
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
  End If
  rs.Close
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to tweak your code a tiny bit, but it lead me to my current solution which works flawlessly! You also helped me understand how rs.MoveNext works. Thank you very much. All I did was change the "if" statement in the middle of your post to..... "If (rs.fields("USER_3").value = "Y") Then"